# How can I set a logical operator between two spread operators in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-state

I'm working on a react project, and I want to init the state in a component like this :

```
state = {
        ...this.props || ...this.initValues
    }
```

where initValues is an object containing all the props but with empty values
I know this is syntactically incorrect, I just want an alternative

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the init values first for spreading and take then the wanted properties.

```
state = {
    ...this.initValues,
    ...this.props
};
```

Comment: just as simple as that, sometimes it feels like "what does 1+1= ?" 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can spread the result of expression. In case if you want just your props or just initial values.

```
state = {
    ...(Object.keys(this.props).length === 0 ? this.initValues : props)
  }
```